# How to run RabbitMQ and Celery Service in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I am having issues while running my Python Flask application from Docker pull (remote pull).
In my app I had used RabbitMQ as message broker, and Celery as task scheduler. It is working as expected when running locally, But when I put my   application on Docker, and Docker pull it from remote system, it runs fine, but Celery and RabbitMQ are not running with it, so all tasks (with method.delay()) are running infinitely and http request is not being processed.

I need help in putting my Python Flask application to Docker, as my application has asynchronous tasks to be processed with Celery. I am not aware about how to modify **docker-compose.yml** for including Celery service.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far in docker-compose.yml to get Celery and Rabbit running?

Comment: version: "3"
services:
 web:
   image:**image_name**
   deploy:
     replicas: 5
     resources:
       limits:
         cpus: "0.1"
         memory: 50M
     restart_policy:
       condition: on-failure
   ports:
     - "4000:80"
 rabbit:
   hostname: rabbit
   image:**image_name**
   environment:
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
     - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
   ports:
     - "15672:15672"
     - "5672:5672"
   tty: true
 celery:
   image:**image_name**
   command: celery worker -l info -A app.celery 
   user: nobody
   volumes:
     - '.:/app'

Comment: the above is my docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @Sunil edit  and add your question with docker-compose.yml file. Don't add large code snippents to comment section

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to link celery container with rabbitmq.
From https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

> Link to containers in another service. Either specify both the service name and a link alias (SERVICE:ALIAS), or just the service name.

```
links:
  - rabbitmq
```

Or

```
  - rabbitmq:rabbitmq
```